# Php передача csv файла пользователю

Tags: php, csv

Мне нужно с базы данных сделать выборку и сформировать файл и предложить пользователю его сохранить. 
С базы данных возвращается  двумерный массив .
Потом я формирую string переменную с данными из массива;

Как поместить  переменную в csv файл и предложить сохранить как ?

Comment: Покажите как пытались сделать сами и тогда обязательно поможем. Объяснять с нуля как производить записи в файл - моветон. Информации же в интернете множество. Ладно, если сложности с кодом, тогда конечно поможем, но если нет стремления разобраться, тут уж извините.

Comment: Хотя бы куда копать? Последовательность. Пробовал сохранять через header

Comment: открываете файл, через `fopen('file.csv', 'w')`, делаете в него записи через `fputcsv`, сохраняете файл через `fclose`. выводите файл через headers `header("Content-Type: application/csv"); header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'";');` Не ленитесь искать информацию.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/151795/

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите, там должен быть ответ на ваш вопрос

[Создание CSV-файла из массива PHP](https://www.khtulhu.org.ua/veb-programmirovanie/219-sozdanie-csv-fajla-iz-massiva-php.html)

[Отдаем CSV файл в браузер](https://www.khtulhu.org.ua/veb-programmirovanie/482-otdaem-csv-fajl-v-brauzer.html)